# Flatten THEN Submit Form from Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have a acrobat form that needs to be flattened before submitting for the purposes of comparing documents.

As of right now, the form submits as expected, but to review correct answers against the answer key when comparing form to form is very difficult.   I have heard LiveCycle might acheive this, but is both expensive and is a maybe.  When the form is flattened, and compared to a flattened answer key, everything is dandy.

I have also tried Javascript, but was told this does not work from READER.

So, is anyone aware of a method to submit a form **made** in Acrobat, **from** reader that is flattened?

Answer (score 0):

Reader can not flatten. Period. Not even the very newest Reader DC can.

In your workflow, you could add a flattener before you do the comparisons.